# Make a simple array from a complex array

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have an array ($query) like this from a database:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [category] => Mercedes
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [category] => BMW
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [category] => Bentley
    )

)
```

I want to make it an array $category:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Mercedes
    [1] => BMW
    [2] => Bentley
)
```

I tried something with array_merge() but the result doesn't look like what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over your array, an pick each 'category' value.

```
foreach ($query as $array) {
    $newArray[] = $array['category'];
}
```

`$newArray` will contain the values as you require.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, where it would recursively flatten a multidimensional array of an arbitrary depth (from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php#104184)):

```
function array_flatten($array) { 
    if (!is_array($array)) { 
        return FALSE; 
    }

    $result = array(); 

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
        if (is_array($value)) { 
            $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value)); 
        } else { 
            $result[$key] = $value; 
        } 
    } 

    return $result; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to cycle through each array inside the array returned from the database:

```
foreach($query as $row)
{
    $category[] = $row['category'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution :

```
$res = array();

foreach ($tab as $val) {
    $res[] = $val['category'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_array = array_map(function($v){return $v['category'];}, $old_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline solution I just came up with:

```
$new = end(call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $arr));
```

Note, this will not work properly if you have more then one element except `category`. If so you can just adopt this solution like this:

```
$new = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $arr);
$new = $new['category'];
```

but this is not that cool and better to go with usual `foreach` way.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved !!.

```
    $query = array
    (
    array
        (
            'category' => 'Mercedes'
        ),

    array
        (
            'category' => 'BMW'
        ),

    array
        (
            'category' => 'Bentley'
        )

    );

    $category = array();

    foreach( $query as $queryArray ){

        foreach( $queryArray as $key => $value ){

             $category[] = $value;

        }

    }

    //echo '<br />';
    print_r( $category );
```